# Setting up ROS2 on laptop with ROS1

Tags: ros, ros2, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi guys I would like to set up ROS2 on my laptop so that I can contribute to the community. However, I have ROS1 installed on my computer. Will this be an issue? If so, what is a good way to prevent any conflicts between the two systems?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/299140/setting-up-ros2-on-laptop-with-ros1/) by [OwnageManFromLOL](https://answers.ros.org/users/30394/ownagemanfromlol/) on ROS Answers with karma: 149 on 2018-07-31

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, I have installed the ROS2 along with the ROS1 `melodic (18.04)`. It doesn't give any conflict with `ROS1`.

Actually, there is bridge between ros1 and ros2.
I suggest you install the ROS2 using Debian package instead of binary installation. please visit [this page](https://github.com/ros2/ros2/wiki/Linux-Install-Debians) and follow the step mentioned there.

```
Note: There can be the conflict of workspace sourcing after the installation. to avoid this conflict you can use the different workspace where ROS1 is not sourced.
```

Focus on the **Sourcing the setup script** part of the provided link

---

Originally posted by [simbha](https://answers.ros.org/users/29493/simbha/) with karma: 241 on 2018-07-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1